# PHP Read input from user

Tags: php, html, forms

I try open url from user input value but its no value

```
<form>
<p>*number:</p>

  <input type="text" name="numberpage" value=""/>

</form>
<a  href="./page.php?page=editdatapo&id=<?php echo $_POST['numberpage']; ?>">find</a>
```

here result that should be

user input = 13

output url

localhost/page.php?page=editdatapo&id=13

but output like this

localhost/page.php?page=editdatapo&id=

Comment: Add `method="post"` in `<form>` tag and add a `submit` button to post form

Comment: or you can use jquery to change link id value on user input event as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form action="./page.php" method="GET">
   <p>*number:</p>
   <input type="hidden" name="page" value="editdatapo" />
   <input required type="text" name="id"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

Try using `GET`. After hitting submit, it will redirect to:

`page.php?page=editdatapo&id=USER_INPUT`

This way, you dont have to use `$_POST` just to access the link. You can just type the id then hit Enter/Find directly.

By default, forms without the `method` attribute uses `GET` and you can omit it if *you really want to*.

Comment: By default form method is always get so no need to write it

Comment: Thanks @ServingQuarantineperiod. I just wanted to emphasize that the form will be using GET. It is better markup on my opinion too. Updated my answer.

Comment: Your approach is totally fine, but it will work perfectly without writing it, because it's by-default

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working code without page refresh:

```
<form>
   <p>*number:</p>
  <input type="text" id="numberpage" value=""/>
</form>
<a href="#" id="findAnchor" onclick="handleAnchorClick()">find</a>

<script>
    function handleAnchorClick(){
        const inputVal = document.getElementById('numberpage').value;
        alert(`./page.php?page=editdatapo&id=${inputVal}`);
        window.location.href = `./page.php?page=editdatapo&id=${inputVal}`;
    }
</script>
```